# How do you run a js file using npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I can't get npm to work. My package.json file has

```
"scripts": { "build": "build.js" }
```

and I have a build.js file in the same folder that just console.logs.

When I run

```
npm run build
```

I get the error

```
The system cannot execute the specified program.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

and if I move the build.js file and change my package.json file to have a subfolder

```
"scripts": { "build": "build/build.js" }
```

then I get the error

```
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What's going wrong? I'm copying the [example documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#examples).

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
{ "scripts" :
  { "build": "node build.js"}
}
```

> `npm run build` OR `npm run-script build`

---

```
{
  "name": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build.js"
  }
}
```

> `npm start`

---

> **NB:** you were missing the `{ brackets }` and the [node](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#default-values) command

folder structure is fine:

```
+ build
  - package.json
  - build.js
```

Comment: Node is needed cause it's needed to launch your script. You can put any command here.

Comment: He wasn't "missing the `node` command", the documentation he linked doesn't have it either.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `npm run-script build` or `npm build <project_folder>`. More info here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/build.

Comment: This doesn't work - same error. The docs say run-script is just an alias for run.